# Microsoft Excel 2016 - Pivot Table is Grouping Dates into only the Month of the Year

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table

Our office recently upgraded to MS Office 2016 and I am used to doing all of this stuff in Python and SQL. Several people still prefer an old excel report that I need to update once a month. I am seeing that the pivot table has collapsed all of my dates into >10-1-2013, the month (Jan, Feb, Mar, etc.), and greater than 7-2-2019. How do I get the pivot table filter to stop doing this?  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPwot.png)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on header and select "Ungroup"
[More info](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/group-or-ungroup-data-in-a-pivottable-c9d1ddd0-6580-47d1-82bc-c84a5a340725)

Answer (score 0):

This is [automatic time grouping](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2015/10/13/time-grouping-enhancements-in-excel-2016/), a new feature in Excel 2016, helps use time-related fields in a PivotTable by auto-detecting and grouping them on your behalf. The automatic grouping creates new Date/Time columns and automatically populates the PivotTable in one action.

You can turn off automatic time grouping. Please review [Turn off time grouping in PivotTables in Excel for Windows](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/turn-off-time-grouping-in-pivottables-in-excel-for-windows-6be5afed-348c-4db2-9f87-5ac262d67b3f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)